# Update SonarQube rules in SonarLint eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

When I change my quality profile on SonarQube, there is a problem to update my profile in SonarLint for Eclipse. I have already link my SonarLint to my SonarQube and it works fine. But when I change rules in SonarQube, for example I disable one there is no update in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

SonarLint for Eclipse doesn't pick up immediately changes to the quality profile of a connected project. It checks from time to time and gives you a warning to *update your bindings*.

You can manually update your bindings if you right-click on the server configuration in SonarLint for Eclipse, in the **SonarQube Servers** view. After that, on the next analysis of your files in Eclipse, the change should be visible.

To open the **SonarQube Servers** view, go to **Window / Show View / Other... / SonarLint / SonarQube Servers**.

Comment: @HenriPineau and it works? (your question is answered?)

Comment: If this answer works for you and your question is solved please consider to mark this question as the right one.